# PYQT5 MDI subwindow the controls move upward than those in design window Why ? Any Solution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qmdiarea

I have designed Main window & subwindow in PYQT5 designer
When I run the code the controls move upwards in the subwindow
But when the subwindow is maximized the controls look correctly spaced from top of window
Also when I resize the subwindow manually the window is not painted correctly but the same is ok when I use Maximize & restore buttons

I want to place objects in subwindow at absolute postion relative the top of sub window

Subwindow Class

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# DataForm implementation generated from reading ui file 'subDataForm.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGridLayout, QWidget, QDesktopWidget, QMdiArea, QMdiSubWindow


class Ui_DataForm(object):
    def setupUi(self, DataForm):
        DataForm.setObjectName("DataForm")
        DataForm.resize(577, 366)
        DataForm.setStyleSheet("")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(DataForm)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 79, 56, 23))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lcdNumber = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(DataForm)
        self.lcdNumber.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 64, 23))
        self.lcdNumber.setObjectName("lcdNumber")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(DataForm)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 294, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(DataForm)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 187, 47, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(DataForm)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 268, 133, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(DataForm)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 242, 69, 20))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")

        self.retranslateUi(DataForm)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(DataForm)

    def retranslateUi(self, DataForm):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        DataForm.setWindowTitle(_translate("DataForm", "DataForm"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("DataForm", "TextLabel"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("DataForm", "PushButton"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("DataForm", "TextLabel"))
```

Mainwindow Class

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'mainform.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGridLayout, QWidget, QDesktopWidget, QMdiArea, QMdiSubWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("E:/tools9/rajsoft.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        #self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.mdi = QMdiArea()
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.mdi)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.mdiArea = QtWidgets.QMdiArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.mdiArea.setObjectName("mdiArea")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.mdiArea)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuMain_Menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuMain_Menu.setObjectName("menuMain_Menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)


        self.toolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.toolBar.setObjectName("toolBar")
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.toolBar)

        self.actionNew_Window = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionNew_Window.setObjectName("actionNew_Window")
        self.actionExit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit.setObjectName("actionExit")
        self.menuMain_Menu.addAction(self.actionNew_Window)
        self.menuMain_Menu.addAction(self.actionExit)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuMain_Menu.menuAction())

        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.menuMain_Menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Main Menu"))
        self.toolBar.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "toolBar"))
        self.actionNew_Window.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Window"))
        self.actionExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
```

Main Program

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from mainform  import Ui_MainWindow
from subform  import Ui_DataForm
from data_toolbar import Ui_FormToolBar

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGridLayout, QWidget, QDesktopWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGridLayout, QWidget, QDesktopWidget, QMdiArea, QMdiSubWindow

class SubForm(QMdiSubWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.subform = Ui_DataForm()
        self.subform.setupUi(self)
        self.tb = Ui_FormToolBar("data_print","n")
        self.tb.setupUi(self)
        self.resizeEvent = self.resized
        self.resize(700, 600)

    def resized(self,event):        
        self.tb.reconfig(self)








class AppWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        colors = QAction('Colors', self)
        exitAct = QAction('Exit', self)
        exitAct.triggered.connect(self.close_application)
        btnTB = QToolButton()
        btnTB.setText("TEST")
        self.ui.toolBar.addAction(colors)
        self.ui.toolBar.addAction(exitAct)
        self.ui.toolBar.addWidget(btnTB)
        self.ui.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.close_application)
        self.ui.actionNew_Window.triggered.connect(self.new_window)
        #center the window
        qtRectangle = self.frameGeometry()
        centerPoint = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qtRectangle.moveCenter(centerPoint)

        sub = SubForm()
        self.ui.mdiArea.addSubWindow(sub)
        self.ui.statusbar.showMessage("HI THERE")
        #sub.move(qtRectangle.topLeft())

        #center the window
        sub.show()


    def close_application(self):
        print("whooaaaa so custom!!!")
        sys.exit()

    def new_window(self):
        sub = SubForm()
        self.ui.mdiArea.addSubWindow(sub)
        sub.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = AppWindow()
w.setWindowState(Qt.WindowMaximized)
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Data Toobar

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_FormToolBar(object):

    def __init__(self,toolbar_type,button_type):
        super().__init__()
        self.toolbar_type = toolbar_type
        self.toolbar_type = self.toolbar_type.lower()
        self.button_type = button_type
        self.button_type = self.button_type.lower()
        self.next_left = 0
        if (self.button_type == "" or self.button_type == "n"):
            self.buttonheight = 41
            self.buttonwidht = 60

        if (self.button_type == "i"):
            self.buttonheight = 29
            self.buttonwidht = 30



    def setupUi(self, FormToolBar):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        FormToolBar.setObjectName("FormToolBar")
        FormToolBar.resize(730, 55)
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(FormToolBar)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 721, 51))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        FormToolBar.setWindowTitle(_translate("FormToolBar", "Form"))

        self.nextleft = 0
        if (self.toolbar_type == 'data' or self.toolbar_type == 'data_print' or self.toolbar_type == 'data_nav' or self.toolbar_type == 'data_nav_print' ):
            self.btn_New = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.frame)
            self.btn_New.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.nextleft, 0, self.buttonwidht, self.buttonheight))
            icon3 = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon3.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("D:/tools9/NEW.BMP"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.btn_New.setIcon(icon3)
            if (self.button_type !="i"):
                self.btn_New.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)            
            self.btn_New.setObjectName("btn_New")
            self.btn_New.setText(_translate("FormToolBar", "New"))        
            self.nextleft = self.nextleft  + self.buttonwidht

            self.btn_Find = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.frame)
            self.btn_Find.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.nextleft, 0, self.buttonwidht, self.buttonheight))
            icon = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("D:/tools9/find.bmp"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.btn_Find.setIcon(icon)
            if (self.button_type !="i"):
                self.btn_Find.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
            self.btn_Find.setObjectName("btn_Find")
            self.btn_Find.setText(_translate("FormToolBar", "Find"))        
            self.nextleft = self.nextleft  + self.buttonwidht + 2


        if (self.toolbar_type == 'data' or self.toolbar_type == 'data_print' )!= True:
            self.btn_First = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.frame)
            self.btn_First.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.nextleft, 0, self.buttonwidht, self.buttonheight))
            icon4 = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon4.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("D:/tools9/Ffc/Graphics/TOP.BMP"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.btn_First.setIcon(icon4)
            if (self.button_type !="i"):
                self.btn_First.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
            self.btn_First.setObjectName("btn_First")
            self.btn_First.setText(_translate("FormToolBar", "First"))
            self.nextleft = self.nextleft  + self.buttonwidht

            self.btn_Prev = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.frame)
            self.btn_Prev.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.nextleft, 0, self.buttonwidht, self.buttonheight))
            icon7 = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon7.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("D:/tools9/Ffc/Graphics/PREVIOUS.BMP"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.btn_Prev.setIcon(icon7)
            if (self.button_type !="i"):
                self.btn_Prev.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
            self.btn_Prev.setObjectName("btn_Prev")
            self.btn_Prev.setText(_translate("FormToolBar", "Previous"))
            self.nextleft = self.nextleft  + self.buttonwidht

            self.btn_Next = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.frame)
            self.btn_Next.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.nextleft, 0, self.buttonwidht, self.buttonheight))
            icon5 = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon5.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("D:/tools9/Ffc/Graphics/next.bmp"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.btn_Next.setIcon(icon5)
            if (self.button_type !="i"):
                self.btn_Next.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
            self.btn_Next.setObjectName("btn_Next")
            self.btn_Next.setText(_translate("FormToolBar", "Next"))
            self.nextleft = self.nextleft  + self.buttonwidht


            self.btn_Last = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.frame)
            self.btn_Last.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.nextleft, 0, self.buttonwidht, self.buttonheight))
            icon10 = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon10.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("D:/tools9/Ffc/Graphics/BOTTOM.BMP"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.btn_Last.setIcon(icon10)
            if (self.button_type !="i"):
                self.btn_Last.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
            self.btn_Last.setText(_translate("FormToolBar", "Last"))
            self.btn_Last.setObjectName("btn_Last")
            self.nextleft = self.nextleft  + self.buttonwidht + 2


        if (self.toolbar_type == 'data' or self.toolbar_type == 'data_print' or self.toolbar_type == 'data_nav' or self.toolbar_type == 'data_nav_print'):
            self.btn_Modify = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.frame)
            self.btn_Modify.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.nextleft, 0, self.buttonwidht, self.buttonheight))
            icon9 = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon9.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("D:/tools9/OPEN.BMP"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.btn_Modify.setIcon(icon9)
            if (self.button_type !="i"):
                self.btn_Modify.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
            self.btn_Modify.setObjectName("btn_Modify")
            self.btn_Modify.setText(_translate("FormToolBar", "Modify"))        
            self.nextleft = self.nextleft  + self.buttonwidht 

            self.btn_Delete = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.frame)
            self.btn_Delete.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.nextleft, 0, self.buttonwidht, self.buttonheight))
            icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("D:/tools9/CUT.BMP"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.btn_Delete.setIcon(icon1)
            if (self.button_type !="i"):
                self.btn_Delete.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
            self.btn_Delete.setObjectName("btn_Delete")
            self.btn_Delete.setText(_translate("FormToolBar", "Delete"))
            self.nextleft = self.nextleft  + self.buttonwidht 

            self.btn_Save = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.frame)
            self.btn_Save.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.nextleft, 0, self.buttonwidht, self.buttonheight))
            icon11 = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon11.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("D:/tools9/SAVE.BMP"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.btn_Save.setIcon(icon11)
            if (self.button_type !="i"):
                self.btn_Save.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
            self.btn_Save.setObjectName("btn_Save")
            self.btn_Save.setText(_translate("FormToolBar", "Save"))
            self.nextleft = self.nextleft  + self.buttonwidht 

            self.btn_Cancel = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.frame)
            self.btn_Cancel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.nextleft, 0, self.buttonwidht, self.buttonheight))
            icon8 = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon8.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("D:/tools9/UNDO.BMP"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.btn_Cancel.setIcon(icon8)
            if (self.button_type !="i"):
                self.btn_Cancel.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
            self.btn_Cancel.setObjectName("btn_Cancel")
            self.btn_Cancel.setText(_translate("FormToolBar", "Cancel"))
            self.nextleft = self.nextleft  + self.buttonwidht 

        if (self.toolbar_type == 'data_print' or self.toolbar_type == 'data_nav_print' or self.toolbar_type == 'nav_print'):
            self.btn_Print = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.frame)
            self.btn_Print.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.nextleft, 0, self.buttonwidht, self.buttonheight))
            icon6 = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon6.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("D:/tools9/PRINT.BMP"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.btn_Print.setIcon(icon6)
            if (self.button_type !="i"):
                self.btn_Print.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
            self.btn_Print.setObjectName("btn_Print")
            self.btn_Print.setText(_translate("FormToolBar", "Print"))        
            self.nextleft = self.nextleft  + self.buttonwidht 

        self.btn_Exit = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.frame)
        self.btn_Exit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.nextleft, 0, self.buttonwidht, self.buttonheight))
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("D:/tools9/CLOSE.BMP"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.btn_Exit.setIcon(icon2)
        if (self.button_type !="i"):
            self.btn_Exit.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
        self.btn_Exit.setObjectName("btn_Exit")
        self.btn_Exit.setText(_translate("FormToolBar", "Exit"))
        self.nextleft = self.nextleft  + self.buttonwidht 




        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(FormToolBar)
        FormToolBar.setTabOrder(self.btn_New, self.btn_Find)
        if (self.toolbar_type == 'data' or self.toolbar_type == 'data_print' )!= True:
            FormToolBar.setTabOrder(self.btn_Find, self.btn_First)
            FormToolBar.setTabOrder(self.btn_First, self.btn_Prev)
            FormToolBar.setTabOrder(self.btn_Prev, self.btn_Next)
            FormToolBar.setTabOrder(self.btn_Next, self.btn_Last)
            FormToolBar.setTabOrder(self.btn_Last, self.btn_Modify)

        if (self.toolbar_type == 'data' or self.toolbar_type == 'data_print' ):
            FormToolBar.setTabOrder(self.btn_Find, self.btn_Modify)
            FormToolBar.setTabOrder(self.btn_Modify, self.btn_Delete)
            FormToolBar.setTabOrder(self.btn_Delete, self.btn_Save)
            FormToolBar.setTabOrder(self.btn_Save, self.btn_Cancel)
        else:
            FormToolBar.setTabOrder(self.btn_Last, self.btn_Modify)
            FormToolBar.setTabOrder(self.btn_Modify, self.btn_Delete)
            FormToolBar.setTabOrder(self.btn_Delete, self.btn_Save)
            FormToolBar.setTabOrder(self.btn_Save, self.btn_Cancel)
        if (self.toolbar_type == 'data_print' or self.toolbar_type == 'data_nav_print' or self.toolbar_type == 'nav_print' ):
            FormToolBar.setTabOrder(self.btn_Cancel, self.btn_Print)
            FormToolBar.setTabOrder(self.btn_Print, self.btn_Exit)
        else:
            FormToolBar.setTabOrder(self.btn_Cancel, self.btn_Exit)        
        FormToolBar.resize(self.nextleft + 10, 55)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, self.nextleft + 8, 54))



    def reconfig(self,parent):
        self.po = parent
        parentwidth = parent.frameGeometry().width()
        parentheight = parent.frameGeometry().height()
        mywidth = self.frame.frameGeometry().width()
        myheight = self.frame.frameGeometry().height() 
        width = ((parentwidth/2) - (mywidth/2))
        height = parentheight- (myheight + 30)
        self.frame.move(width,height)
        self.btn_Exit.clicked.connect(sys.exit)
        self.frame.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue happens because you are setting an absolute position based on the *window* geometry, which can also include the title bar; in your case the vertical position will always be `window.y() + titlebar.height() + y`, so if the window is maximized the titlebar will have no height, thus showing the "correct" position you wanted.

The correct implementation of a QMdiSubWindow is to use [`setWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdisubwindow.html#setWidget) to add its contents. It's almost like using `setCentralWidget()` for a QMainWindow.

```
class SubForm(QMdiSubWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # create the widget and set its ui
        self.subform = QWidget()
        subform_ui = Ui_DataForm()
        subform_ui.setupUi(self.subform)

        # set the widget for the window
        self.setWidget(self.subform)

        # you should *not* do this!!!
        self.tb = Ui_FormToolBar("data_print","n")
        self.tb.setupUi(self)
```

About the last lines, you should *never* call setupUi more than once on the same widget, and not even against an object that has a class different from what it expects: in your case, Ui_FormToolBar should be a QWidget, but you're using with a QMdiSubWindow instead; while it seems to work, you might face some serious problems in the future. What you should do is to create a separate QWidget and use the form setupUi with it.

Finally, I strongly suggest you to **not** edit the python files generated by `pyuic` to create your programs; read the official documentation on how to correctly [use the files created with Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code) instead.

Comment: It did the job 

# you should *not* do this!!!
        self.tb = Ui_FormToolBar("data_print","n")
        self.tb.setupUi(self)
But it was to add form button group class which are common to all data forms cannot be added in designer from the class

Comment: @user2035041 That was referred to the second line (the `self.tb.setupUi(self)` call), as explained in the second to last paragraph: you already called a `setupUi` against `self` and you shouldn't do that again, especially starting from another Ui class. Create another QWidget (eg. `self.otherWidget = QWidget()`) and then use `tb_ui.setupUi(self.otherWidget)`. That said, I really suggest you to follow the documentation about using designer I linked at the end of the answer.